# How to say "season's / personal best (result in sport for athlete)" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, sport

How to say "season's best (result in sport for athlete)" in Chinese?

I mean there could be personal best (all time, does not matter this or past or past-past year), and seasonal best result (only this year). How to say this?

Answer (score 3):

年度最佳(best in this year)

季度最佳(best in this seanon)

个人最佳 (personal best)

all 佳 can be replaced by 好, the first 2 words can be prefixed with 上(last year), 2007 (in 2007).

Comment: But searching (google, baidu) on the net does not give any appropriate results, e.g.: 年度最佳100米,  刘翔2009年度最佳110米

Comment: Because we don't track the score with too much details like that. If someone want to emphasize time, hey may also say '创下今年最好的记录".

Answer (score 1):

Seasonal best(only this year): 赛季最佳（球员/队员/选手）

Its sister term 'MVP': 最有价值（球员/队员/选手）

Answer (score 1):

> *I mean there could be personal best (all time, does not matter this or past or past-past year)*

个人最佳 (personal best)

> *and seasonal best result (only this year).*

本季最佳/ 今季最佳 (best **this** season)

If it is a term ball-sport, we can call it 本球季最佳

For all other sports, we say 本赛季最佳 or 今个赛季最佳

Answer (score 1):

> (某运动员)这个赛季的最佳成绩。

[Kimi拿到赛季最佳成绩不指望法拉利夏休期大幅提升](http://sports.sina.com.cn/f1/2014-07-28/00127269058.shtml)